# How does JavaScript decide sort order with characters from different character sets?

Tags: javascript

I was working on some code where I need to perform an alphabetic ascending sort (standard `.sort()`) behavior and I wondered how sorting works with special characters and characters from different character sets. For example:

```
var aChars = [];

aChars.push("¢");
aChars.push("™");
aChars.push("È");
aChars.push("~");
aChars.push("p");
aChars.push("_");
aChars.push("P");
aChars.push("治");
aChars.push("す");

aChars.sort();

for (var i = 0;i<aChars.length;i++) {
    console.log(aChars[i]);
    //alert(aChars[i]);   
}​
```

I always get a consistent order when I execute this code. How does JavaScript decide the order? I thought it might be by HTML entity number, but I can't find an HTML entity number for those Japanese characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't provide your own comparision function, then per the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.mit.edu/~gsstark/e262-pdf.pdf), here are the rules:

1. If x and y are both undefined, return +0.
2. If x is undefined, return 1.
3. If y is undefined, return -1.
4. If the argument comparefn was not provided in the call to sort, go to step 7.
5. Call comparefn with arguments x and y.
6. Return Result(5).
7. Call ToString(x).
8. Call ToString(y).
9. If Result(7) < Result(8), return -1.
10. If Result(7) > Result(8), return 1.
11. Return +0.

For your particular case, it is determined by steps 7-11.

And, the `<` and `>` operators compare the Unicode encoding value of the first differing character.

For finer grain control over the situation, MDN recommends using your own custom compare function that uses [`String.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) which contains a bit smarter logic for sorting characters.

Comment: @pst - Ahhh, I see what you were talking about now.  That was a weird copy/paste problem from the spec PDF.  It's correct in the PDF, but when copying text, the negative signs were dropped.  They must end up in the clipboard being something other than a dash and the browser drops them when pasting.  Thanks for fixing.