# Find matches between given data

Tags: javascript, sorting, ascii, alphabetical

I have seen that sort function in javascript transforms every letter of a word in ascii code to permit the comparison between words when an alphabetical sort is required.How this function manage to find asciI code for every letters?Does It slide a list for every letters?
What is the method with the function associate ascii code to a letter?
Thank you so much for help:)

Comment: If you do `'A'>'B'` it'll return `false` because in ASCII 'A' is < to 'B'. I think it could help. You also have `yourChar.charCodeAt(0)` that gives you the ASCII code

Comment: How the function manage to associate this code to every letter?

Comment: are you looking for "a".charCodeAt(0) and "b".charCodeAt(0)

Comment: I know the existence of this method but what I don't understand is how this method associate ascii code or unicode point to the letters...

Comment: It is a standard : http://unicode-table.com/en/.  Alternatively, are you asking how "A" is stored in memory?

Comment: Ok,but how javascript manage to associate this standard value to every letters during the execution of the function?This is what I don't understand:(I don't understand then the two downvotes at my question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082043/how-does-javascript-decide-sort-order-with-characters-from-different-character-s

Answer (score 0):

Abstractly, characters *are* numbers in that what we think of as a character "a" and the number "97" are both a byte "‭01100001‬".

It is a lot more nuanced than that as unicode supports multi-byte characters and numbers in javascript are multi-byte floating points but the concept holds at a high level.

An "encoding" such as ASCII, WE8DEC, or one of the Unicode flavors is essentially a way to map a (set of) byte to what we think of as a character.

So, if numbers can be sorted, then so too can characters and thus strings.

You might also be interested in this post that explains the native sorting rules : [How does JavaScript decide sort order with characters from different character sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082043/how-does-javascript-decide-sort-order-with-characters-from-different-character-s)